# Image with an InputText of PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am intending to put an image next to an InputText like a "*" which changes to a green (another image) when something valid is typed in the InputText. How will I be able to put an image along with the InputText?

Answer (score 2):

If a "*" is all you want to add , just add something like

```
<h:panelGroup styleClass="#{myBean.valid?'geen':'red'}">*</h:panelGroup>
```

next to your input...

Answer (score 0):

You can also make it interactively using ajax:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{userBean.name}">
        <a4j:ajax event="keyup" render="out1,out2" />
    </h:inputText>

    <!-- For a textual * -->
    <h:outputText value="*" styleClass="#{userBean.valid?'green':'red'}" id="out1" />

    <!-- For an image -->
    <h:graphicImage value="#{userBean.valid?'/img/valid.png':'/img/notvalid.png}" id="out2"/>
</h:form>
```

Sorry for using **RichFaces** tag **a4j:ajax**, I suppose there is an equivalent tag in **Primefaces**.

Regards,